# Passing resource-locking object as parameter

Tags: c++, reference, raii

What is a good way of passing an object as a parameter? In my code, I have been using references instead of pointers, and I would like to stick to this approach if possible. However, there is one case where this does not work properly:

```
class Resource {
    Resource(...) { //expensive resource initialization }
    ~Resource() { //destroy resource }
};

class User {
    User(const Resource & res) : res_(res) { //initialize user }
private:
    Resource res_;
}

void Init() {
    Resource res(...);
    User user = new User(res);
} //res is destroyed - along with its associated resource
//user can no longer use the resource
```

Are there any best practices that should be used in such a scenario? The result I want to achieve is to destroy the `Resource` automatically when the `User` object is destroyed, but not rely on the `User` object to create the `Resource` itself. My feeling is that I should overload the copy constructor of `Resource`. Any other ideas?

Comment: Do you want to share `Resource` object between `User` objects, or just have them created external to the `User` objects?

Comment: I need to share them between `User` objects as well.

Comment: Without knowing more about the design, I'm guessing you want something like `shared_ptr`, which is available in boost, tr1 or the c++11 standard, depending on the age of your tool chain.  http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best shot is holding a `shared_ptr<Resource>` member in `User` class. But this requires the resource to be generated on the free (heap) memory.

```
class User {
  User(Resource * res) : res_ptr(res) { //initialize user }
private:
  shared_ptr<Resource> res_ptr;
}

void Init() {
  Resource * res = new Resource(...);
  User user = new User(res);
}
```

Second approach is providing a fake copy constructor and a swap mechanism for `Resource`.

```
class Resource
{
private:
  explicit Resource(const Resource &); // disabled to avoid heavy copy.
  const Resource & operator = (const Resource & );
  int * int_res;
public:
  Resource() : int_res(new int(100)) { } 

  ~Resource()
  {
    if(int_res != NULL)
      delete int_res;
  }

  Resource(Resource & other) : int_res(NULL) 
  {
    this->swap(other);
  }

  void swap(Resource & other)
  {
    using std::swap;
    swap(int_res, other.int_res);
  }
};

class User
{
private:
  Resource resource;
  User();
  User(const User &);
  const User & operator = (const User &);
public:
  User(Resource & res) : resource(res) {  }
  ~User() { }
};
```

But this is dangerous and error-prone because after creating the user, you leave the resource in a zombie state. For this piece of code, all access to the `int_res` pointer, which is assgined to `NULL`, will give you access violation error.

The last approach I can explain is using a C++0x feature "move semantics".

```
class Resource
{
// ...
// ...
  // Replace with Resource(Resource & other)
  Resource(Resource && other) : int_res(NULL) //Move constructor
  {
    this->swap(other);
  }

  const Resource & operator = (Resource && other) // Move assignment operator
  {
      this->swap(other);
      return *this;
  }

  void swap(Resource & other)
  {
    using std::swap;
    swap(int_res, other.int_res);
  }
};

class User
{
private:
  Resource resource;
  User();
  User(const User &);
  const User & operator = (const User &);
public:
  User(Resource && res) : resource(std::move(res)) {  }
  ~User() { }
};

void Init() {
    Resource res(...);
    User user = new User(std::move(res));
}
```

This approach is some how safer. You don't have to deal with pointers and if you forget to write `std::move`, you will get a compiler error saying "you cannot bind a `Resource` instance to `Resource&&`" or "copy construtor of `Resource` is disabled."

`&&` emphasizes the object is temporary and is going to evaporate. So this approach is more suitable for scenarios where Resource is generated and returned by a function. If I were you I would make the constructor private and generate it with a friend function.

```
Resource GetResource(....)
{
  Resource res(...);
  return res;
}

void Init() 
{     
  User user = new User( GetResource(...) );
}
```

This piece of code is perfectly performant with "move semantics". You must learn it if you are able to write C++0x code. [This](http://skillsmatter.com/podcast/home/move-semanticsperfect-forwarding-and-rvalue-references) and [this](http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Going+Deep/C9-Lectures-Stephan-T-Lavavej-Standard-Template-Library-STL-9-of-n) are two good videos to start with.

Comment: `User(Resource * res) : res_ptr(res)` Don't mix and match -- either use `shared_ptr<>` or raw pointers, not a combination of both.

Comment: @ildjarn: I am constructing a `shared_ptr` inside `User` class with a pointer to `Resource`. What is the downside of this?

Comment: The downside is that `Resource` takes ownership of the raw pointer -- these semantics are not obvious. However, they would be if `Resource` took a `shared_ptr<>` rather than a raw pointer.

Comment: If in class `User` I have a member of type `Resource` but I construct it in the initializer list of the `User` constructor, won't the `Resource` object be constructed before the `User`? Doesn't this mean that the `Resource` member will never be in a "zombie state"? Or is this not what you meant?

Comment: @dandrestor: AFAIK, `Resource` will be constructed, in the order of initializer list, after the `sizeof(User)` memory is allocated. The zombie state is the state in which the object is not useful anymore, but and derefencing the object will not cause an error.

Comment: @dandrestor: e.g. in the construction of `Resource`, a new `int_ptr` is allocated. But when a `Resource` is move to another, `int_ptr` is set to `nullptr`. Here the resource with the null `int_ptr` is said to be in the zombie state. Now you have to be careful and design the `Resource` object with the possibility of `int_ptr` being null in order to avoid errors.